# Need help creating a trigger that limits the Quantity from exceeding as specific number

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I have been working on this question here

> Create a Word document that includes the SQL query code used to
> explore the database tables and answer the following questions.
>
> Write a trigger titled "tgrExcessInventory" for the Production.ProductInventory table to ensure the quantity can never exceed 800 units.
> Modify the trigger created in step 1 to execute its check code only if the Quantity column is updated.

I can create a trigger but not sure how to specifically single out one column and make sure that each value of the column is either equal to or less that the max number and if it hits that number then the update rolls back.

I looked online and came up with this but it is not working

```
create trigger tgrExcessInventory
on Production.ProductInventory
after insert, update 
as 
begin 
    declare @Quantity int
    select @Quantity = Quantity from inserted
    Select @thecount = Count(*)
    from Production.ProductInventory
    where Quantity = @Quantity

    if (@thecount >= 700)
    begin 
        raiserror('you cannot do that' , 15, 0)

        rollback 

end
```

these are are the errors I am getting

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tgrExcessInventory, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@thecount".
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure tgrExcessInventory, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Must declare the scalar variable "@thecount".
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tgrExcessInventory, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Incorrect syntax near 'end'.
>
> Completion time: 2019-08-04T15:01:01.9509212-04:00

Comment: You have tagged MySQL but it looks more like SQL Server to me. Which DBMS is this for?

Comment: sorry it is SQL Server

Comment: I have modified the tags.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't use `Select @thecount = Count(*)` without first declaring `@thecount` just like you did for `@Quantity`

Comment: Your trigger assumes that only one row will be updated as well; it shouldn't. Considering,however, that `quantity` is a column this shouldn't be a trigger, it should be a check constraint.

Comment: You are over-thinking things. Your first goal does not require you to count anything - so why are you doing that? Your goal is to prevent any row from having a value of quantity > 800. A text description of your code is: if any rows exist where the quantity is greater than 800, then generate an error. Your code is as simple as that statement. Another hint - use EXISTS().